# Android firebase count element

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to count elements in a firebase database, I have seen different topics and tried this code:

```
final Query dataQuery = myRef.equalTo(MainActivity.user.getUid()).getRef();
    dataQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.e("ERROR",""+dataSnapshot.child(MainActivity.user.getUid()).getChildrenCount());

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
```

Now, the value in log error is correct but, if I try to assign it in field, or static field is always 0 out of this method;
How can I use this value in other class?

Comment: That's because Firebase loads data asynchronously. Where else do you want to use this value?

Comment: I want use it in my main class, for create a toDo list with exactly database element numeber.

Comment: I can tell you're a beginner in Android.  I recommend checking out [this tutorial](https://inducesmile.com/android/a-simple-android-todo-list-app-with-recyclerview-and-firebase-real-time-database/) to build your app. Or take the [Free Android Course on Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/new-android-fundamentals--ud851). This will help you learn the best practices and make your app better. The way you have designed it right now makes it hard for us to help.

Comment: Did that answer help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a callback and call a method on the callback in your onDataChange. Then once that callback is returned you can continue with the rest of your logic.

You can see an example of that here:

https://github.com/Austin-Android/austin-feeds-me/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/austindroids/austinfeedsme/data/firebase/FirebaseEventsDataSource.java#L40

```
fireBase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Event event = snapshot.getValue(Event.class);
                events.add(event);
            }
            callback.onEventsLoaded(events);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply take that value and use it outside `onDataChange()` method, because it will always be `null`. This is happening because this method has an asynchronous behaviour, which means that is called even before you are getting the data out from the database. A quick fix would be to use that value only inside `onDataChange()` method, or to dive into the asynchronous world and see the last part of my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774).